# How to define trait for adding to Seq?

Tags: scala

I have a beginners Scala question. I have a class, Sample which extends the trait SampleAPI. Now I'm trying to build a sequence of Sample instances using seq. I will look something like this:

```
var samples: Seq[SampleAPI] = Seq()
for(...) {
    samples :+= new Sample(...))
}
```

This gives me the following compiler error: "type mismatch; found : Seq[java.lang.Object] required: Seq[se.uu.medsci.queue.setup.SampleAPI]"

So I tried:

```
samples :+= (new Sample(sampleName, this, illuminaXMLReportReader)).asInstanceOf[SampleAPI]
```

Which instead throws a runtime exception, saying that Sample cannot be bast to SampleAPI. I guess that this comes down to a problem in my understanding of the use of traits in Scala. Any help in figuring this out would be much appreciated.

Comment: can't reproduce your compiler error, works just fine with `
trait SampleAPI;
class Sample extends SampleAPI;

var samples: Seq[SampleAPI] = Seq();
for (i <- 1 to 10) {
  samples :+= new Sample()
}`

Comment: You should really post all of the relevant code and specify to which line the error corresponds. A minimal example that reproduces the error would be ideal.

Comment: You are right @KimStebel it works, if you extend then Sample as I wrote, but had missed to do in my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the compiler error coming up on this line?

```
samples :+= new Sample(...))
```

If so, I think the problem is that your `Sample` class doesn't actually extend `SampleAPI`.

What's happening has to do with the [contravariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) type parameter of the `List` type in Scala. If you start with a `List[SampleAPI]`, then add a `Sample` to that list, it needs to find the least-upper-bound on the types included in the list to use as the new type parameter. If `Sample` is a `SampleAPI`, then the least-upper-bound is just `SampleAPI` and you get a `List[SampleAPI]` as the result of the `:+=` operation. However, if `Sample` is *not* a `SampleAPI` then the least-upper-bound on the two types is just `Object`, hence your compiler error saying that it was expecting a `Seq[SampleAPI]` but found a `Seq[Object]`.

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right. I forgot to extend Sample with SampleAPI, one of those end-of-the-day-misstakes.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working now. I hope my explanation of the error mades sense so that next time you'll have an easier idea understanding what the compiler is complaining about!

Comment: Your explanation was great. Thanks.